# OverFlow Specific Elements

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a pie chart however I have a problem.

I need to set `overflow:visible` only for the `div` from it's right and for the rest as `hidden`.

http://jsbin.com/vifogufu/4

As you can see there are 3 colors, although I set 4. The cyan hides the yellow (to see the yellow just right on `#first that z-index=1` it's already in comment there...

I had no success yet. Any ideas how can I fix it?

Thanks :)

Comment: please post you current attemp and a demo if possible.

Comment: @NicoO i just did...you need to hover on the right top and go to "edit" if you want to see the code :)

Comment: In firefox i only see two colors.

Comment: is  this what you are looking for ? http://jsbin.com/vifogufu/5/edit

Comment: @NicoO check again (i changed the url adress)

Comment: Check this: http://jsbin.com/vifogufu/5/edit

Comment: @Ani I wrote there sizes at the function in the javascript section It should be matched for the size, in this case the third is half not 13/24 and the cyan is 6/24 instead of 2/24 etc...

Comment: Then your total angle goes beyond 360 - don't you want to make sure it's total 360 degree

Comment: @Ani it's 360... Can you look at the js code? I measured how much percent it should be from the circle

Comment: @SaharTi7 There is no any problem in your code except that commenting `z-index` The following demo is from all values equals to 6 i.e the total 24, you will find equivalent colors area and this is happened by the portion of your valus. http://jsbin.com/vifogufu/4/